# JavaScript chart.js syntax error if statement

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, slim

We are using the chart.js library. The framework used is Slim from Rails. I'm using JavaScript.

I get an Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if' error in the
> if(user.activity_type === "groupA").

```
 script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"
  javascript:
    var users = #{raw @user.to_json}
    let count = 0;
    let month = "";
    let array = [];
    var ct = document.getElementById('ex_chart');
    var ex_chart = new Chart(ct, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: users.map((user) => (
                    if(user.activity_type === "groupA") {
                        if(month === "" || month === user.month) {
                          count += user.count;
                        } else {
                          array.push(count);
                          count = user.count;
                          month = user.month;
                        }
                      return array;
                    }
              ),
              backgroundColor: '#ff7f50'
            }},
            {
              data: [880, 740, 900, 520, 930],
              backgroundColor: '#ff6347'
            }
          ]
          });
        },
        options: options
    })

    var options = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 300
                }
            }]
        }
    };
```

Comment: Check your parens, `data: users.map((user) => ( ` should be `data: users.map((user) => {`

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function should have curly braces instead of parentheses. Try replacing `data` with this:

```js
data: users.map((user) => {
    if(user.activity_type === "groupA") {
        if(month === "" || month === user.month) {
          count += user.count;
        } else {
          array.push(count);
          count = user.count;
          month = user.month;
        }
      return array;
    }
}),
```

Notice the curly brace right after the arrow and the one before the parenthesis on the last line.

Comment: {} Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error.

Comment: Excuse me. It was because I was typomis.
When I tried to execute the process, no error occurred, but the variable of array was still []. why is it?

Comment: It looks like `month` is never updated, so it's always equal to empty string. So the code in your else statement will never run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{}` rather than `()` in map

It should be like this:

```
script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"
javascript:
  var users = #{raw @user.to_json}
  let count = 0;
  let month = "";
  let array = [];
  var ct = document.getElementById('ex_chart');
  var ex_chart = new Chart(ct, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
      labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
        datasets: [
            {
            data: users.map((user) => {
                    console.log("user", user);
                    if(user.activity_type === "groupA") {
                        if(month === "" || month === user.month) {
                        count += user.count;
                        } else {
                        array.push(count);
                        count = user.count;
                        month = user.month;
                        }
                    return array;
                    }
            }),
            backgroundColor: '#ff7f50',
            },
            {
            data: [880, 740, 900, 520, 930],
            backgroundColor: '#ff6347'
            }
        ]
      },
      options: options
  })
```

Comment: {} Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error.

Comment: You had a mistake in your code. Please find that and do what I said.

Comment: Here you go. I made that for you.

Comment: Excuse me. It was because I was typomis.
When I tried to execute the process, no error occurred, but the variable of array was still []. why is it?

Comment: Maybe your `users` has no data. Please check it. I insert a console.log in your code after the `map`. Look at the code again.

Comment: The data was in the user.

Comment: Your conditions was satisfied? Please see your `if` conditions.

Comment: You have to check your conditions first.